# Cordova shareable google route map links breaking on iPhone and Android

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova, url-scheme, inappbrowser

My app has an several shareable route map links that are formatted as follows and no longer work - meaning they won't natively open in the browser.  Instead, both iPhone and Android see the link and are trying to open in Google Maps APP - which breaks the links:

```
var link = https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=14DdJfOLp26RFilzX0tp2hs_M7gBBNFkk&ll=27.931760141489143%2C-82.47564270000004&z=16
window.open(link,'_system','location=yes') ;
```

I found similar issues from users talking about the problem, but the fix (if it works) requires the user to tweak some settings on their phone.  (issue: https://support.google.com/maps/thread/8806737?hl=en  ) which for app developers is not a solution.

Previously when opening the links it would natively open in the phones/system default browser (ie: chrome/safari) and everything worked fine.  Recently this behavior has changed.  Both iPhone and Android phones now seem to recognize the url `google.com/maps` causing the system to ask the user to open this link in their Maps app....or in the system browser.  On iPhone, it doesn't even ask, it just defaults to using the map app.  If the user chooses to open in the map app (or on iPhone it simply defaults to it), the above shareable route map won't load - saying map can't be found (or some other error).

On Android, since it at least asks the user:  Maps or Chrome - if the user chooses Chrome then the link will work.

This new default behavior is causing shareable route maps to break on iPhone...and on Android where users choose Maps over Chrome.

On Android, I found a way to force these types of maps to use Chrome by using a url scheme.  Forcing the map to chrome would look like:

window.open("googlechrome://" +link,'_system','location=yes') ;

However, a url scheme does not exist for Safari on iPhone...causing even this kind of work around to still break on iPad and iPhones.

Either google needs to allow shareable maps back on the default Map app....and/or iPhone needs to create a specific url scheme for Safari....preferably both.

OR....does anyone else have a fix/work around for this on iPhone - or in general?